# Should I encrypt Local Storage in React.js?

Tags: reactjs, encryption, redux, local-storage, cryptojs

I'm persisting my Redux store as a string in Local Storage.
Before I save it, I'm encrypting it with Crypto-js.

Does it have any benefit besides that it is not human-readable?

Comment: Its not human readable that is the benefit

Comment: Then, the question will be: what is the benefit, that it is not human-readable?

Comment: ... Encryption has a single goal: hide information.

Answer (score 2):

I cant see any particular benefit apart from the average user not being able to read it. However if a user was determined enough, they could easily find the key and decrypt it, since its all sitting client-side.

Comment: The key is saved as a secret and read as am environment variable. Therefore it is not so easy to decrypt it.

Comment: Then how is it encrypted/decrypted on the client? the only way it could be saved on the client is if they had knowledge about the key encrypting it

Comment: Even more succinct: if you are encrypting local storage for any reason _besides_ to prevent casual user readability, you're doing it wrong.